# Update partial serializer data

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am manually creating a model instance with `Job.objects.create()` but I want to use `self.serializer.create()` but I don't know how to add remaining partial data.
Now I just want

```py
class JobCreationView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobCreatorSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        rounds = RoundSerializer(data=request.data['rounds'], many=True)
        rounds.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        eligibility = EligibilitySerializer(data=request.data['eligibility'])
        eligibility.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        job = self.serializer_class(data=request.data['basic'], partial=True)
        job.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        # after running all `is_valid` we confirm that there is no error

        data = dict(request.data)
        del data['rounds']
        del data['eligibility']

        job = Job.objects.create(
            **data['basic],

            # company can't be null
            company=request.user.account.company,

            # eligibility can't be null
            eligibility=eligibility.save()
        )
        job.rounds.set(rounds.save())

        return Response({
            'detail': f'Created Job {job.id}'
        }, status=201)
```

I want something like this

```py
        rounds = RoundSerializer(data=request.data['rounds'], many=True)
        rounds.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        eligibility = EligibilitySerializer(data=request.data['eligibility'])
        eligibility.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        job = self.serializer_class(data=request.data['basic'], partial=True)
        job.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        job.validated_data['eligibility'] = eligibility.save()
        job.save()

        job.rounds.set(rounds.save())
```

The actual question that how to update serializer data after checking `is_valid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need to update the data. You can pass extra values directly to `.save()` method. [See this part of documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save)

```py
serializer = SomeSerializer(data=some_data, partial=True)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
serializer.save(some_exta_data=value1, some_exta_data2=value2)
```

So,

```py
class JobCreationView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobCreatorSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        rounds = RoundSerializer(data=request.data['rounds'], many=True)
        rounds.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        eligibility = EligibilitySerializer(data=request.data['eligibility'])
        eligibility.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        job = self.serializer_class(data=request.data['basic'], partial=True)
        job.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        job.save(eligibility=eligibility.save(), company=request.user.account.company)
        job.rounds.set(rounds.save())

        return Response({
            'detail': f'Created Job {job.id}'
        }, status=201)
```